# What's the story behind the mugs in Deep Space Nine and Babylon 5?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, babylon-5, food

As much as I personally love *Deep Space Nine*, a case can be made that major features of the show were ripped off of *Babylon 5*.  Although the first episode of *DS9* hit the airwaves six weeks before the first *Babylon 5* television film, it is widely known that Paramount had access to *Babylon 5* creator J. Michael Straczynski's show bible for some time.  (For further reading on this, see [here](http://www.tor.com/2013/02/26/is-this-the-smoking-gun-proving-deep-space-nine-ripped-off-babylon-5/).)

Apart from the broad similarities, I noticed that the same distinctive style of mug appears in both shows.

[Raktajino (Klingon coffee)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Raktajino) and its preferred serving mug appear for the first time in the Season 1 *DS9* episode ["Dax"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dax_(episode)), which aired February 14, 1993.  Here is a screenshot from the episode, showing Dr. Bashir with the mug:

[image: Bashir holding a Raktajino mug]

Now here is a nearly identical style of mug in *Babylon 5*, as seen in its Season 1 episode ["Eyes"](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Eyes):

[image: Mugs in Babylon 5]

This episode aired on July 13, 1994.  The mugs began appearing in *Babylon 5* a few episodes prior to this one, but they still appeared in *DS9* more than a year earlier.

**Is there a story behind the use of these mugs in *Babylon 5*?  Was this a subtle attempt to draw attention to *DS9* having copied crucial elements of *Babylon 5* ?**

**Update:** As a commenter and an answerer have pointed out, these mugs have a real-world naval precedent, but consider the following:

- **(a)** I found it odd that both shows should choose to use that style of mug at the same time, especially as no other spacefaring shows of the time had them;
- **(b)** in-universe, the Replimats on DS9 almost certainly produced Cardassian-style drink containers, and so out-of-universe the intention was likely to have a *foreign-looking* mug rather than a mug tied to human naval traditions;
- **(c)** neither Deep Space Nine nor Babylon 5 is a ship — under routine operations, neither station would expect turbulence or "heavy seas", supported by the fact that we often see glassware in use, especially on *Babylon 5*.

Comment: [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Babylon_5#Star_Trek_references_in_Babylon_5) doesn't make mention of it and the Babylon Five wiki doesn't even acknowledge Star Trek!

Comment: @N_Soong : Yep, I checked Memory Alpha and the Babylon 5 Wikia first.

Comment: just a speculation, but I remember there were a variety of unusual drink containers shown on Next Generation (do a google image search for next generation ten forward drink to see some), it's possible that they were ordering them from some specialty manufacturer rather than the prop people making the containers themselves, in which case it's possible other sci fi shows like Babylon Five might order from the same manufacturer.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : That's an interesting point...which could become an answer if you can track down a common prop manufacturer. :-)

Comment: That's not a "Raktajino mug", that's a plain old no-tip mug that you can probably buy anywhere you'd buy other mugs.

Comment: I probably couldn't find the manufacturer, but it seems to be a preexisting style of mug that the prop guys may have just decided to adopt because it looked unusual, I found [this etsy page](https://www.etsy.com/listing/104225499/wide-bottom-coffee-mug) showing such a mug which is supposedly from the 1970s. And if you search "wide base mug" on eBay you find a bunch of examples with car brand logos like [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Black-Gold-FELTMAN-LANGER-Mug-Mate-AUDI-Mug-Cup-w-Lid-NO-SLIP-Wide-Base-NIB-/221602804390?hash=item33988e72a6), maybe the style is made for driving?

Comment: @muistooshort : It's a Raktajino mug because there's Raktajino in it.  Just like a coffee mug is a coffee mug because there's coffee in it.

Comment: And [here's another ebay set](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1980-Set-of-2-Promotional-Mugs-for-Post-Toasties-Cereal-No-Tip-No-Spill-/361369717217?hash=item54235049e1) from 1980, you can tell they're old based on old logo for a discontinued Post cereal called "Toasties".

Comment: @Hypnosifl : Maybe I should edit to make it clear that I'm not claiming it's not a preexisting mug.  I just think it's quite the coincidence that *both* shows have the same type of unusual mug.  A coincidence that could be explained by a conscious decision, or by having the same supplier, as you point out.  :-)

Comment: It is a coffee mug because I used to drink coffee out of one. It is also a yerba maté mug because I used to drink that out of one too. I'd imagine that they're quite common among sailors and space fleets all pretend to be navies so...

Comment: @muistooshort : Fair enough.  I changed the wording.  See edit.  :-)

Comment: If it's just a preexisting style then there are probably many different manufacturers of that kind of mug, so the fact that prop people on both shows would go for the same widely-available alternative to a normal modern mug style doesn't seem like it'd be too big a coincidence. It's hard to see the Babylon 5 mug very clearly in that picture but to me the shape looks slightly different than the DS9 mug shown on [this page](http://www.trekprops.de/raktajino-mug-replimat), I think the bottom part of the handle is closer to the place the base meets the vertical side on the B5 mug for instance.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : You can see the *B5* mug more clearly in other episodes, but this is the only screenshot I could find.

Comment: Related question - how on earth can you clean them? Doesn't old coffee get stuck in the ridge at the bottom?

Comment: I recall that in one of the extras on one of the DVD releases of DS9 one of the prop people told how she delighted in finding odd containers (glasses, bottles, mugs,...) for use in Quark's bar (and elsewhere). Considering that she acquired existing products, it stands to reason that other prop people also encountered these; so most likely it's just just coincidence that both shows ended up using similar mugs.

Comment: @muistooshort No. It's not a no-tip mug. It's a *space* mug.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 Only sci-fi nerds would have a holy war over mug terminology :)

Comment: They were known as "tumble-not mugs". I'm sure they appeared in a few Next Generation episodes. Also available as merchandise, including Next Generation branded. eg https://www.flickr.com/photos/leongking/4917403188

Comment: DS9 lifted guest stars off B5 enough, I'm not surprised they borrowed their mugs.

Comment: FYI, I'm pretty sure I've seen this mug in Farscape as well, but since I first saw it I haven't been able to find it again. If anyone is up for a Farscape-race, I would love to get closure on that question.

Comment: Didn’t they have these in *Next Gen* too, before DS9 was on the air?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

## About the mugs

The important thing to note is that in DS9 there are two types of Raktajino mugs:

### Hotjo mugs (from Quark's)

[This site](http://www.trekprops.de/raktajino-mug-quarks-bar) claims that:

> These mugs were made by HighWave and were **called “HotJo”**. The model
>   line was modernized however, so that the older ones are not available
>   anymore. The current HotJo mugs were also used in later seasons of DS9
>   however.

A [quick search on the Highwave site](https://www.highwave.com/products/hotjo) results in this

[image]

which look like they've been updated from the ones seen in DS9 and Babylon 5

[image]

### Mugs from the Replimat

Again from the [same site](http://www.trekprops.de/raktajino-mug-replimat)

Here's a picture of one; compare it to the one in the question that Bashir is holding:

[image]

## Back to the Question

So, we're focused on the **mugs from the replimat** from DS9.  Now, if you look *very* closely at the photo in the original question, you can see the handle on the Babylon 5 mug is much more angular than the one in the above picture of the mugs from the Replimat:

[image]

Nevertheless, there are some clear similarities in the design.

In a quote in 1996 about the similarities between the two series generally from Straczynski said:

> For now, I'm asuming [sic] it's all just coincidence.

([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Babylon_5#Babylon_5_and_Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine))

So, considering that Straczynski did suspect there was some copying occurring, but gave them the benefit of the doubt, to me it seems Straczynski wouldn't have ordered this intentionally.  To my mind, **the most likely explanation for this is that both companies approached a different manufacturer and selected different, but similar, mugs that looked futuristic.**  The fact that they look awfully similar is probably simply because they were being produced around the same time so the concepts of what constituted 'futuristic' were similar.

Now, I've gathered all the evidence I can find to support this contention, but ultimately it is just speculation based on evidence on my part.

Comment: Great research, @N_Soong!  I'm particularly happy that you found a statement from JMS on the matter.  :-)

Comment: Great answer, but I'd quibble with "approached the same manufacturer"--like I said in another comment, it seems to be a preexisting style of mug (search for "no tip" or "no spill" mug and you'll find many) so this style was probably made by a lot of different manufacturers--the very fact that the two mugs have slightly different shapes may suggest mugs from two different companies.

Comment: Convergent evolution of mugs, no doubt.

Answer (score 60):

I believe this style is a [no-spill mug](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/137430226102353411/) for ships in heavy seas. That would mean both shows drew inspiration from the same real-world precedent.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm looking for something a little more definitive, in terms of statements from the creative staff, prop people, etc.

Comment: I added some points to the end of the question that should clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: Were the residents of DS9 expecting the space station to tilt to one side and spill out the mugs?

Comment: @RichS, blame the Cardassian gravity technology.

Comment: +1, interesting to discover they have a positive purpose in real life, I always assumed they were cool looking but less practical to drink from space mugs